# Compilation warnings - deprecation and no definition of serialVersionUID

Tags: java, swing, warnings

I am trying this code below but it is giving me warning message but when I execute it runs without error.

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
class MyFrame extends JFrame {
    public  MyFrame() {
        setTitle("Besm Allah Ya Allah");
        setSize(300,300);
        setLocation(10,100);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        JFrame f = new MyFrame();
        f.show();
    }
}
```

`javac -Xlint MyFrame.java` gives me:

```
MyFrame.java:13: warning: [deprecation] show() in Window has been deprecated
f.show();
 ^
MyFrame.java:3: warning: [serial] serializable class MyFrame has no definition of serialVersionUID
class MyFrame extends JFrame {
^
2 warnings
```

What is the problem? Why I'm getting warning messages?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See [`Window#show`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#show%28%29):

[image]

You should use [`Window#setVisible(true)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#setVisible%28boolean%29).

For your second warning, see [`Serializable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html):

> A serializable class can declare its own serialVersionUID explicitly
>   by declaring a field named "serialVersionUID" that must be static,
>   final, and of type long

Comment: Thanks a lot that really i want it like ex. teach me how to drive better than driving for me.